# Can I use setup assistant to move files to a Mac with a newer OS?

Tags: macos, data-transfer, setup-assistant

I would like to migrate all my accounts, settings and applications from a OSX 10.7 Lion Mac Pro to a brand new OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion iMac.

Would Setup Assistant be able to move my files to a newer OS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Lion and Mountain Lion are compatible in this regard.

You can read [Apple's official support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889) for details on completing the transfer.